# I am not able to write content to var file

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I am not able to write content to `var` file.

```
/var/www/html
sudo groupadd www
sudo usermod -a -G www ec2-user
sudo chown -R root:www /var/www
sudo chmod 2775 /var/www
find /var/www -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} \;
find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} \;
```

The commands executed. I get permission denied each time I try  creating `phpinfo` in `var` folder.

```
echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/phpinfo.php

Comment: is this solved?

Answer (score 2):

Permission is given only to the owner (root) and group (www). When you run

```
echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
```

The user must be a root or belong to group www.
Any other user or group will be denied to access the filesystem.

Comment: At least in my case this is turning out to be a webserver/php config issue, not a filesystem permissions issue.  ie.  sudo echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/example.com/phpinfo.php can also result in the "Permission denied" error and the user issuing it is obviously "root".